# Android Issue with menu's not openning on Samsung devices

Tags: android, optionmenu

Android Issue with menu's not opening on Samsung devices

1. Menu key pressed.
2. onPreparaeOptionsMenu called adding > 6 menu items.
3. Menu's "MORE" button is selected.
4. Any menu item is selected.
5. Menu key pressed.
6. onPrepareOptionsMenu called removing all items and adding < 6 menu items.
7. Menu is NOT displayed.
8. Pressing menu key no longer calls onPrepareOptionsMenu.

   ```
   public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
   menu.clear();
   if (isLess) {
       menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Menu 0");
       menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Menu 1");
       menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Menu 2");
       menu.add(0, 3, 0, "Menu 3");
       menu.add(0, 4, 0, "Menu 4");

   } else  {
       menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Menu 0");
       menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Menu 1");
       menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Menu 2");
       menu.add(0, 3, 0, "Menu 3");
       menu.add(0, 4, 0, "Menu 4");
       menu.add(0, 5, 0, "Menu 5");
       menu.add(0, 6, 0, "Menu 6");
       menu.add(0, 7, 0, "Menu 7");
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menu options not working on Android

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
     openOptionsMenu();
     return true;
   }
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```